# problemas em usar o inputFile no JSF 2.1

Tags: jsf, xhtml

Eu estou usando a versão JSF 2.1 com esse artefato abaixo;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.21</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

E preciso usar o inputFile como mostra a baixo;

```
        <p:outputLabel value="Imagem do Produto" />
        <h:inputFile value="#{cadastroProdutoBean.arquivo}" />
```

Eu sei que é necessário usar a tag seguintes abaixo;

```
xmlns:i="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
```

sendo que não reconheci, o que será que está errado? O que é preciso para eu fazer o inputFile ser reconhecido na pagina?

Atualização da postagem///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Estou com uma enorme dificuldade para habilitar o inputFile do JSF, pois eu soube que o inputFile somente funciona no projeto JSF da versão 2.2.
Então resolvi criar o projeto do Zero e conseguir converter para a versão mais recente como podem ver;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais ainda tenho problemas e preciso de ajuda.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54245/discussion-on-question-by-wladyband-problemas-em-usar-o-inputfile-no-jsf-2-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo,

Ao incluir a linha `xmlns:**i**="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"` você nomeou esse `pool` de componentes com a letra **i**.
Sendo assim, tente utilizar o componente com a seguinte tag

```
<i:inputFile value="#{cadastroProdutoBean.arquivo}" />
```